# Vim - delete until find a pattern, but in reverse direction

Tags: vim

I know how to delete a part of text from cursor position to occurence of pattern, I mean <kbd>d</kbd>`/<pattern>`. I am wondering how to delete a part of text before cursor position until occurrence of pattern which is before cursor position.

Being in position x in file:

```
>>>>
aaaa
===x
bbbb
<<<<
```

I want to delete

```
>>>>
aaaa
====
```

This is work if pattern is exists only once in file... and vim doesn't have a choice. However there is a problem with file like this:

```
>>>>
aaaa
====
bbbb
<<<<

foo
boo

>>>>
cccc
====
dddd
<<<<
```

Comment: Have you tried d `?<pattern>`?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: this seems to not work for me. Correction! This is work! Please write your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can search backwards using `?`. So to delete back until a pattern, use <kbd>d</kbd>`?<pattern>`.

Answer (score 1):

One can delete ahead using f or t. For example d2f_ would delete up to and including the second underscore, and d2t_ would delete up to but excluding the second underscore. I just tried with gVim on a machine running you-know-what and it works in reverse if you capitalise the f or t. So d2F_ would delete BACK TO and including the second-to-last underscore and d2T_ would delete BACK TO but excluding the second-to-last underscore.

I'm so happy to have found this that I could just press my cheek glands.